Excel MsgBox Ok/Cancel
I have a procedure that should only start if a condition is met.
In this example the condition is ActiveWindow.Zoom = 200
Trying to use a MsgBox with vbOkCancel to say:

check the window zoom level:

if it's already set to 200: start
if not: inform the user and give two options:

Ok = change zoom level to 200 and start
Cancel = don't change and exit





Issue: The code starts the procedure, if the active window zoom is already set to 200. Otherwise, it only sets the zoom to 200 and exits.
Sub AddChart()
  '... 
  If Not ActiveWindow.Zoom = 200 Then
    MsgBox "Set Window Zoom to: 200%", vbOKCancel
  Else
  ActiveWindow.Zoom = 200
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  With ws
  '...
  End With
  End If
End Sub


You should read carefully how If ..Else works . Using If...Then...Else statements

Your code tests if the Zoom is set to 200. If it is not, it warns you to change it. If it is, it sets it anyway..?
You should use:
If Not ActiveWindow.Zoom = 200 Then
    MsgBox "Setting Window Zoom to: 200%", vbOKOnly
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 200
End If



Using vbOkOnly as @CLR suggests

Sub AddChart()
  '... 
  If Not ActiveWindow.Zoom = 200 Then
      MsgBox "Setting Window Zoom to: 200%", vbOKOnly, "Info"
      ActiveWindow.Zoom = 200
  End If
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  With ws
  '...
  End With
End Sub


Using vbOkCancel

Sub AddChart()
  '... 
  Dim Result As Integer
  If Not ActiveWindow.Zoom = 200 Then
  Result = MsgBox("Setting Window Zoom to: 200%", vbOKCancel, "Info")
    If Result = vbOK Then
       ActiveWindow.Zoom = 200
    Else: Exit Sub
    End If
  End If
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  With ws
  '...
  End With
End Sub 

